# Accessing td's within a tr in CSS

Tags: javascript

So I have a function that needs to handle a `<tr></tr>` and get the 3rd `<td>` tag in it

How would I access the 3rd `<td>` tag inside this

TRinput = the following

```
<tr>
  <td>Sup</td>
  <td>9</td>
  <td>5</td>
</tr>
```

how would i access the 3rd td

```
TRinput.(whatgoes here to access the 3rd td)
```

Comment: access it to set the contents inside? what's the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by third you mean the last one, there is a `lastElementChild` property that fits perfectly your need

```js
const tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0]
console.log(tr.lastElementChild)
// content accessed with:
console.log(tr.lastElementChild.innerText)
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Sup</td>
  <td>9</td>
  <td>5</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you but how do I get the text inside the element with out the <td></td> tags? For example its returning <td>5</td> and I want just 5 how would i do that?

Comment: with [`innerText`](//mdn.io/innerText) or [`innerHTML`](//mdn.io/innerHTML)

Comment: I'm gettting an error for both "innerText is not a function"

Comment: Because **it is not a function** but a property, did you try to call it (i.e `el.innerText()`)?

Comment: Still, **not a function**, remove the parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `TRinput` is the `<tr>`

```
TRinput.children[2]
```

will allow you to access the third cell if you're using vanilla JS. [Lansana's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45681865/1376145) covers the case if you're using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Do the following in your CSS:

`tr > td:nth-child(3)`

This says that for the 3rd *direct* child of a tr, apply a style.

If you are using something like jQuery, you can similary do:

`$('tr > td:nth-child(3)')`

Please check the [CSS Pseudo-classes reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) for more information.

Comment: OP didn't tag or mention JQuery nor CSS, so this does not answer the question